# Return string array from dll function

Tags: c++, delphi, delphi-7

How can I return a string array from C++ dll and then the function will be call by a Delphi application.

I tried:

C++ dll

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

extern "C"
{
    __declspec( dllexport ) void arrayStr(vector<string> s)
    {

        s.push_back("111");
        s.push_back("222");
        s.push_back("333");
    }

}
```

Delphi

```
procedure arrayStr(StrMem : TStringList); cdecl; external 'arrayStr.dll';
...
var
  StrMem : TStringList;
  i : integer;
begin
  StrMem := TStringList.Create;
  arrayStr(StrMem);
  for i := 0 to StrMem.Count-1 do
  begin
    ShowMessage(StrMem[i]);
  end;
  StrMem.Free;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

The `TStringList` (Delphi) is incompatible with C++ STL containers.

You should do the following:

**C/C++ side:**

```
void __stdcall Func(char **strings, int count);
```

**Delphi side:**

```
type PPAnsiChar = ^PAnsiChar;
procedure Func(ArrayOfStrings: PPAnsiChar; CountOfArray: Integer); stdcall;
```

Comment: Dynamic array in Delphi is incompatible with char**, better to add a length parameter and a pointer or a fixed size array

Comment: @Andrew: Then I'd adjust my answer if I were you.

Comment: Made changes required

Comment: No, that won't work. Keep trying. Or perhaps it would be better to give up, delete this, and let the user read the excellent answer at the dupe